# Reshape a data frame in R but not with aggregated functions

Tags: r, reshape

I'm trying to build a pivot table from this data frame below. *"VisitID"* is the unique ID for a user who came to visit a website, *"PageName"* is the page they visited, and *"Order"* is the sequence of the page they visited. For example, the first row of this data frame means "user 001 visited Homepage, which is the 1st page he/she visted".

```
    VisitID            PageName             Order
      001              Homepage               1
      001              ContactUs              2
      001              News                   3
      002              Homepage               1
      002              Careers                2
      002              News                   3
```

The desired output should cast *"VisitID"* as rows and *"Order"* as columns, and fill the table with the *"PageName"*:

```
                 1           2          3
      001     Homepage    ContactUs    News                                             
      002     Homepage    Careers      News
```

I've thought about using reshape::cast to do the task, but I believe it only works when you give it an aggregated function. I might be wrong though. Thanks in advance for anyone who can offer help.

Comment: Well, you could have tried it to see what would happen.

Comment: test1 <- dcast(test, VisitID ~ Order, value.var = "PageName"), and the error message was "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length"

Comment: This is not an error, this is a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to aggregate. As long as there's only one row for each combination of columns in the casting formula, you'll get the value of `value.var` inserted in the output.

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(mydata, VisitID ~ Order, value.var="PageName")
```

Here's an example:

```
# Fake data
dat = data.frame(group1=rep(LETTERS[c(1,1:3)],each=2), group2=rep(letters[c(1,1:3)]),
                 values=1:8)
dat
  group1 group2 values
1      A      a      1
2      A      a      2
3      A      b      3
4      A      c      4
5      B      a      5
6      B      a      6
7      C      b      7
8      C      c      8
```

Note that rows 1 and 2 have the same values of the `group` columns, as do rows 5 and 6. As a result, `dcast` aggregates by counting the number of values in each cell.

```
dcast(dat, group1 ~ group2, value.var="values")
```

> ```
> Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
>   group1 a b c
> 1      A 2 1 1
> 2      B 2 0 0
> 3      C 0 1 1
> ```

Now lets remove rows 1 and 5 to get rid of the duplicated `group` combinations. Since there's now only one value per cell, `dcast` returns the actual value, rather than a count of the number of values.

```
dcast(dat[-c(1,5),], group1 ~ group2, value.var="values")
```

> ```
>   group1  a  b  c
> 1      A  2  3  4
> 2      B  6 NA NA
> 3      C NA  7  8
> ```

Comment: I tried this code before but it threw an error: "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length"

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. It means you have more than one value in at least one of the cells. You can have a maximum of one value per cell if you want to avoid aggregation. `defaulting to length` just means that when you don't specify an aggregation function and there is more than one value in at least one cell, `dcast` will use the `length` function (which counts the number of values in each cell) as the aggregation function.